# Create a laravel post to create a variant product creator system

Tags: php, laravel, post

I am creating a CMS for an E-commerce and I am having problems developing a system to create variants of products.

I have the frontend developed and it seems like the image:
[image]

As you can see, the system generates possible variants using the type of product in question. Then, the admin has to select which variants wants to create and click the submit button.

What I think is to make a form post, and get the request on the controller. With this approach, the request only contains the selected variants. But now, I have to create the variants and store them on DB, and with this information, I don't know how to make a dynamic iteration for each variant selected.
For example, if I press the submit button on the image, I get the following request:

```
{
    "_token":"OQElUkt7zMaxr1JkZU6fw1r9gcaBuLa6gXHKSsex",
    "row-check-0":"0001-0001",
    "row-check-1":"0001-0002",
    "row-check-2":"0001-0003",
    "row-check-3":"0001-0004",
    "row-check-4":"0001-0005"
}
```

To create a variant I need the **N.º de producto** and the **Referencia** values. For example, row1 would be a variant with code: "0001-0001" and value:"1"

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="inside">
    {!! Form::open(['url' => '/admin/products/'.$product->id.'/variants/new']) !!}
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center; width:5%">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="masterCheck" value="checkUncheckAll">
                </th>
                <th scope="col">N.º de producto</th>
                <th scope="col">{{$product->type_product->name}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $count = 0;
                $last_code = 0;
            ?>
            @foreach($no_used_values as $no_used_value)
                <?php
                    $last_code = getNextCode($last_code);
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="table-text" style="padding: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row{{$count}}" name="row-check-{{$count}}" value="{{$product->code.'-'.$last_code}}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-text">{{$product->code.'-'.$last_code}}</td>
                    <td class="table-text">{{$no_used_value->value}}</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $count++;
                ?>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="dialog-button-bar-variants" class="dialog-button-bar">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="goToValues()">&lt;&lt; Atrás</button>
        {!! Form::submit('Crear Variantes', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
        <div>   
            {!! Form::close() !!}           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**// EDIT**

```
<div class="inside">
    {!! Form::open(['url' => '/admin/products/'.$product->id.'/variants/new']) !!}
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center; width:5%">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="masterCheck" value="checkUncheckAll">
                </th>
                <th scope="col">N.º de producto</th>
                <th scope="col">{{$product->type_product->name}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $count = 0;
                $last_code = 0;
            ?>
            @foreach($no_used_values as $no_used_value)
                <?php
                    $last_code = getNextCode($last_code);
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="table-text" style="padding: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row{{$count}}" key="row-check" name="last_codes[{{$product->code.'-'.$last_code}}]" value="{{$no_used_value->value}}" >
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-text">{{$product->code.'-'.$last_code}}</td>
                    <td class="table-text">{{$no_used_value->value}}</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $count++;
                ?>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="dialog-button-bar-variants" class="dialog-button-bar">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="goToValues()">&lt;&lt; Atrás</button>
        {!! Form::submit('Crear Variantes', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
        <div>   
            {!! Form::close() !!}           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
public function postProductsVariantCreator($id, Request $request){
    //$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    foreach ($request->last_codes as $key => $value) {
        //code to store the variants
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me to find a solution to achieve it.

Comment: _"To create a variant I need the N.º de producto and the Referencia values."_ - well then I would suggest you include those in the data you are posting ... (Although the checkbox values appear to contain your N.º de producto already.)

Comment: are you asking for the opinion on how you should do it ?

Comment: Your question is still not clear, do you want help editing the form html ? The id of the product is not in the url ? what have you tried ? what issues did you encounter ? please read this topic to improve your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: better now? @N69S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing you checkbox input to this

```
<td class="table-text" style="padding: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <input type="hidden" name="{{$product->code.'-'.$last_code}}" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" id="row{{$count}}" name="{{$product->code.'-'.$last_code}}" value="1">
</td>
```

You will receive in your request

```
{
    "_token":"OQElUkt7zMaxr1JkZU6fw1r9gcaBuLa6gXHKSsex",
    "0001-0001":"1",
    "0001-0002":"0",
    "0001-0003":"1",
    "0001-0004":"1",
    "0001-0005":"0"
}
```

Where the value will be 0 or 1 depending if the checkbox is checked or not

**--EDIT--**

A better solution is to use the structure of an array.

```
<td class="table-text" style="padding: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <input type="hidden" name="{{$product->code.'-'.$last_code}}" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" id="row{{$count}}" name="last_codes[{{$product->code}}][{{$last_code}}]" value="1">
</td>
```

This will result in a data structure like this

```
{
    "_token":"OQElUkt7zMaxr1JkZU6fw1r9gcaBuLa6gXHKSsex",
    "last_codes":[
        "0001":[
            "0001":"1",
            "0002":"0",
            "0003":"1",
            "0004":"1",
            "0005":"0"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Controller Code

```
public function postProductsVariantCreator($id, Request $request){
    //$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    foreach ($request->last_codes as $productCode => $lastCodes) {

        //here you can fetch the product using the $productCode

        foreach($lastCodes as $lastCode => $enabled) {
            //here you have access to $lastCode && $enabled where $enabled = 1 or 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how can I iterate this request in the controller? @N69S

Comment: @martibellot that the subject of another quest. you can use foreach($request as $key=>$value) and explode the key. if the result of the explode is not two strings, then ignore it. But i have a better solution for you, will edit it soon

Comment: Ok, thanks, but think that the $product->code will always be the same for all the variants on that page, so all values will go to the same array element. Can you please post the code of the iteration?

Comment: @martibellot the more reason to set it as a parent key (even if its a lone element) to make it easier to access the child. As for th iteration conde, just double foreach it. if you want the complete code, add the code you tried in your question.

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's what I want.

Comment: @martibellot added some details to the controller code